# Making a pivoted view writtable

Tags: oracle11g, triggers, pivot

We are current on Oracle 11g.

I created a view (View A) which joins multiple tables.  I then create a another view (View B) using PIVOT.

The requirement is to make View B writable, so I use the Trigger to do an INSTEAD OF.

The challenge is that inside of the trigger, I have to write an individual INSERT statement for each non-null pivoted column and these columns can grow.  I don't want to be modify the trigger every time a column is added.  Is there an elegant to way to handle this situation?

Thanks

*P.S.  I have made a honest effort to search the net, but come up empty, so you know or think there's a duplicate article out there, simply let us know and don't down vote the question.  Appreciated very much!  :)*

Comment: You have to modify the view to add the column, so why is modifying the trigger at the same time a problem?

Comment: @Alex...The column could grow and shrink as the developers manipulate the values.  Imagine before the pivot, the column holds values A, B and C.  If the developer or user introduces D, the pivot will have 4 columns.

Comment: The pivot clause has to have a fixed number of output columns though - and the view query defines the columns in the view. If you add data that means you need an extra `pivot ... for ( ... )` value for D, it won't automatically show up in the view?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that for 11g.